# Vaadin how to capture / handle refresh, reload event

Tags: user-interface, vaadin, page-refresh, vaadin-flow, vaadin10

I started learning Vaadin recently, up to this point i did not have much experience with web-based applications, so my question might be very basic.

I want to use eventbus, when create a new layout i register it in the eventbus, it looks like this:

```
    this.addDetachListener(e ->{
                eventbus.getBus().unregister(this);
                System.out.println("addDetachListener");
            }
    );

    this.addAttachListener(e ->{
                eventbus.getBus().register(this);
                System.out.println("addAttachListener");
            }
    );
```

My problem occurs when i refresh the page, I noticed that every time when i reload the page (hit the reload button in the webbrowser) Vaadin is creating new UI and register this view in the eventbuss.

When i click refresh button i expect detachListener to fire up, but it does not work, so i end up with many UI registered in the eventbuss.

**How can i capture refresh event in Vaadin ?**

Comment: Please note that i already tried to use [at]UIScoped and [at]VaadinSessionScoped  from: import com.vaadin.cdi.annotation.UIScoped;
import com.vaadin.cdi.annotation.VaadinSessionScoped;  but vaadin still is making new UI after each refresh hit.

Comment: In order to use it this way, you need to use @PreserveOnRefresh which changes the behavior so that existing UI is used instead of a new bring created.

Comment: Where can i find this annotations ?

Comment: I tried both import com.vaadin.annotations.PreserveOnRefresh; and com.vaadin.flow.router.PreserveOnRefresh; both do not work, do i need to do anything more tan adding dependency in POM and later inport the package ?

Comment: It is a new feature in Vaadin 14 that was just released, see documentation https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-preserving-state-on-refresh.html